# Get Duration of Mp3 using Shell32.Shell

Tags: c#, winforms

I have below code to get mp3 file duration, but it return empty string.
The file is located in drive c:

```
private string GetDuration(string FileFullPath)
{
    string duration = "";
    string fName = FileFullPath.Substring(FileFullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    string filePath = FileFullPath.Substring(0, FileFullPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
    Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
    Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(filePath);
    Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(fName);
    if (folderItem != null)
    {
        duration = folder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 21); //Only Empty for 21
    }
    folderItem = null;
    folder = null;
    shell = null;
    return duration;
}
```

Comment: Where is the 21 coming from? According to this documentation, only values -1 through 4 are documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2266316/17034).  Audio is {64440490-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}, the length property is 3, unit is milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I added this string prop = (string)itm2.ExtendedProperty("{64440490-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 3"); it gives the error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.UInt64' to type 'System.String'.